# How to use random class with parameters?

Tags: java, parameters

How do I create parameters with the random class? I do this but it sends out an error message.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class DiceSimulation { 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
          final int NUMBER = 10000;

         Random generator = new Random();

         int die1Value; int die2Value; int count = 0; int snakeEyes = 0; 
         int twos = 0; int threes = 0; int fours = 0; int fives = 0; 
         int sixes = 0;

         while (count < NUMBER) {

              die1Value = generator.nextInt(1, 6); 
              die2Value = generator.nextInt(1, 6);

              if (die1Value == die2Value)   { 
                    if(die1Value == 1) { snakeEyes++; } 
                    else if (die1Value == 2) { twos++; } 
                    else if (die1Value == 3) { threes++; } 
                    else if (die1Value == 4) { fours++; } 
                    else if (die1Value == 5) { fives++; } 
                    else if (die1Value == 6) { sixes++; }

              }     
              count++; 
         }
```

Comment: ..... what's the error? CTRL+SHIFT+F your code.

Comment: Java has this wonderful thing called [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). Read it, and you'll see what methods are available, what they do and how they work.

Comment: Please see how your question looks in Preview before clicking submit button next time. I have formatted your code this time. After writing your code, just select all the code, and use `CTRL + K` to format your code.

Answer (score 4):

Syntax is incorrect. Please read [`Java Doc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). You can write method like below.

```
 public static int generateBetween(int number, int max) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int generated = random.nextInt(max - number);//<--Between so Max -Number
    return generated+number;//<--Add here number so that it will be between
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is wrong:

```
  die1Value = generator.nextInt(1, 6); 
  die2Value = generator.nextInt(1, 6);
```

`nextInt(int)` accepts only one parameter so change it as below:

```
  die1Value = generator.nextInt(7); //This will generate int between 0 & 6
  die2Value = generator.nextInt(7); //This will generate int between 0 & 6
```

If you want to generate range based random, then use a workaround using `nextDouble()` which generates the value between `0.0` and `1.0` as below:

```
die1Value= 1+ (int)(generator.nextDouble()*5);//This will generate int between 1&6
die2Value= 1+ (int)(generator.nextDouble()*5);//This will generate int between 1&6
```

Syntax:

```
  die1Value = min+ (int)(generator.nextDouble()*(max-min));
  die2Value = min+ (int)(generator.nextDouble()*(max-min));
```

Comment: Incorrect. Read the javadoc of `Random.nextInt()`.

Comment: @JBNizet: If you mean `6` was exclusive, I corrected the answer. If its about Random#nextInt(int), here is the javadoc-[Random#nextInt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)).